# Basic Probability in a Sports Series

Tags: probability

My friend and I were discussing this and are unable to come to a consensus on who is right.

Assume Team 1 has $3$ wins and Team 2 has $2$ wins series where, in order to win the series, you have to win 4 games. The three possible outcomes are Team 1 wins the 6th game and wins the series, Team 2 wins the 6th game then loses the 7th game so Team 1 wins the series, or Team 2 wins both games 6 and 7 so they win the series.

What is the probability that Team 2 wins the series? Would it just be 25 percent?

Comment: Are you assuming that each game is independent and that each Team has a $\frac 12$ probability of winning?  If so, then yes.

Comment: Yes if they were independent events that would be true, but I don't believe they would be in this case.

Comment: Fair enough, but in that case you do not have enough information to answer the question.